# Calling Obj-C library from Corona application

Tags: ios, objective-c, lua, coronasdk

I have a large library written in Objective-C that I would like to use from a Corona app (as a plugin).

I read that Corona Enterprise supports native libraries so long as it is wrapped in a Lua interface.

What is the process of wrapping a native library? Would it be easier to write the library in plain Lua instead?

Answer (score 0):

Corona Enterprise allows you to build a Corona SDK based application that can call Objective C or native Java routines (for Android).  You end up building a native app that calls your Corona code.  There are bindings that let you pass data between Obj-C/C++ methods and Lua.